# What standards should a commercial encryption device meet?

Tags: encryption

I am trying to build a commercial encryption device. Ok, I know how to write code, how to transform encryption algorithms from the book into code and construct electronics. But my question is: what should I take care of in order to implement a **commercial** encryption device (ECC, RSA, AES)?

Comment: While FIPS is the correct answer, be aware that it is _not_ sufficient. Even DES-ECB is FIPS-compliant.

Comment: In which country do you want to sell it?

Comment: I will contact my laywer to see if it is legal to patent and sell such a device first, I am thinking of Europe. If it is not legal, I will not build anything...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[foreverska's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/260966/17515) gets an upvote, but I'll give more detail.

## For US government: FIPS 140-2 / 140-3

The US government has the [FIPS 140-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/140/2/final) or the newer [FIPS 140-3](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/140/3/final) standard outlining the design requiremnts for cryptographic modules that are acceptable for use by the US government.

To claim that your product is FIPS 140-3 compliant, you need to get it tested by a certified lab, and it has to be [listed here](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search/all).

Since you mention hardware, I'll note that there are 4 levels with increasing security requirements, where level 1 is about correctness of the algorithms, and levels 2, 3 & 4 are focused on hardware security, like detecting physical tampering of the device and wiping memory, and robustness to physical side-channel attacks like power or EM analysis, abusing the device with very high temperature or voltage, etc. Level 4 is exceedingly hard to obtain and even most of the big-name HSM vendors only certify to level 3.

[Wikipedia gives a good description of the levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2#Security_levels).

## For international markets: Common Criteria

[Common Criteria](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/) is a set of crypto standards that are recognized by 31 countries, similar to FIPS.

[The list of certified products and vendors is here](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/products/).

Comment: As of now, FIPS 140-2 is dead - NIST is not accepting any new applications for FIPS 140-2 approval (even if you got in the paperwork instantly, which is obviously not the case).  FIPS 140-3 is the only road at the moment.

Comment: @poncho Yeah, I know that in my brain, but I found literally no 140-3 certifications on the [validated modules](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search/all) page; even ones that were granted like last week.

Comment: Note that to *claim* your product is FIPS compliant you don't need to get it tested. You do need to get it tested if you want to claim it's FIPS certified. I mean you can *claim* it's certified without having it tested but there are laws against that in most countries.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your customer.

Most devices aim for FIPS compliance

https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/140/2/final